# short url in R package documentation

Tags: r, documentation

I am writing a documentation of an R package and want to document where the data come from, but it's a long complicated url. Is there a way to give `\url{}` with an alias like "find data `here`" (where you get to the link when you click on "here").

In MediaWiki it works like this: `[http://mediawiki.org MediaWiki]`and you get a link called "MediaWiki" that leads you to http://mediawiki.org.

I tried: 
`\url[here]{http://www.r-project.org}`, `\url{here}{http://www.r-project.org}` or `\url{http://www.r-project.org}{here}`,  `\url{http://www.r-project.org here}` and the LaTeX command `\href{http://www.r-project.org}{here}`

My google search showed nothing, so I suppose what I want to do is not possible...

Comment: `\href{http://mediawiki.org}{MediaWiki}` should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this excerpt from Wickham's book [R Packages: Object documentation](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html) for some tips. Including these options for URLs:

- `\url{http://rstudio.com}.`
- `\href{http://rstudio.com}{Rstudio}.`
- `\email{hadley@@rstudio.com} (note the doubled @).`

Comment: It works! I did try ```\href{http://rstudio.com}{Rstudio}``` but from what I recall I got an ever repeating error message until I deleted my package library manually. I might have taken that error for an indication that ```\href{}{}``` doesn't work.

Comment: Another thing: using ```\%``` for ```%``` in the url works for ```\url{}``` but not with ```\href{}{}```. The ```\%``` remains in the link and hence the url can't be opened. I solved this by replacing ```%2F``` by ```/```and ```%3D``` by ```=``` for example.